# Creating a survey weights variable

Tags: r, survey, survey-weights

I'm a survey weight novice, and I'm trying to implement survey weights in an analysis for the first time.

Let's say I have some variable of interest, X, in a dataset but that dataset provides no weight variable that I can quickly implement in the analysis.

But, I do have the following crosstab for X that I can use in creating a weight variable.

```
|--------------|------|---------|
| Age in Years | Male |  Female |
|--------------|------|---------|
| 18-29        |  0.1 |    0.15 |
| 30-44        |  0.2 |    0.19 |
| 45-59        |  0.1 |    0.11 |
| 60 +         |  0.1 |    0.13 |
|--------------|------|---------|
```

I'm sure it's not a very difficult procedure to create a weight variable out of this information, but I'm not entirely sure where to begin.

Is it that for every row of X that corresponds to "60 +" years and "Female", I code a weight value of 0.13? And for every row of X that corresponds to "60 +" years and "Male", I code a weight of 0.1? And so on? Or is it something else entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of survey weights is to make your sample closer in distribution to the target population. You need to know what the corresponding table for the whole population would look like.

Suppose that in the population 12.32% of people are Male aged 18-29. In your sample there fewer people in this category, so you want to give them extra weight. Each person in this category would get a weight of 12.32%/10% = 1.232.  And so on.

Strictly speaking, these are calibration (post-stratification) weights rather than sampling weights, but they get used in basically the same way.